# Goのfmt.Printが機能しない

Tags: windows, go, powershell

Go言語でfmt.Printを使ってデバックをしようと思ったのですが、なぜかうまく表示されません。
何かわかる事や予測があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

## 動作環境

- Windows10
- Powershell
- Go1.10
- [ソースコード](https://gist.github.com/NAKKA-K/bdd5a57caeb6e4a26d776a3722740a97)

## 試したこと

1. `fmt.Print`で出力しても表示されない
2. `fmt.Printf`を使用しても表示されない
3. `fmt.Fprint`を使用しても表示されない
4. `fmt.Print`の出力をリダイレクトで外部ファイルに出力すると問題なく出力されていた
5. `fmt.Printf`や`fmt.Print`の最後に\nをつけて使用すると正常に表示された
6. `fmt.Print`を使用してそのまま表示し、直後に`fmt.Print`で\nを出力すると先のprint内容も表示された

## 考えたこと

**\n**がC++等で使用する、`flash`や`<< end`のような役割を持っているのかと考えた。
だがそれならその他の出力時に一緒に表示されなければおかしい。
ならば何かしらの要因で無かったことにされたのかとも考えたが、その可能性もないだろうと思いなおす。

## 結論

結局何もわからなかったので、少しでも意見が欲しいと思い質問させていただきました。

Comment: 手元の環境(Linuxですが)では正常に動きました。引数としてファイルを指定して動作するようですが、その内容に関わらず動かない感じでしょうか？

Comment: > fmt.Printfやfmt.Printの最後に\nをつけて使用すると正常に表示された
改行回りが原因のような気がします。`fmt.Println`を利用してみては如何でしょうか

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
Linuxで正常に表示されたとなるとやはり改行コード周りが問題ですかね。

ただ改行されない、とかでしたら分かるのですが、表示されないというのはいかんせん納得できない現象です。
Goの内部仕様で実は今回該当する何かの条件が満たされていないパターンなんでしょうか。
fmt系の実装を見てもあまり詳しいことはわかりませんでした......。